# Efeito Marginal para GLM (logit) com variáveis categóricas.

Tags: r

Tenho a seguinte regressão:

```
Call:
glm(formula = IN_FIN_REEMB_FIES ~ CO_CATEGORIA_ADMINISTRATIVA + 
CO_COR_RACA_ALUNO + IN_RESERVA_VAGAS + IN_RESERVA_ENSINO_PUBLICO + 
CO_TURNO_ALUNO + IN_RESERVA_RENDA_FAMILIAR + IN_FIN_NAOREEMB_PROUNI_PARCIAL + 
TP_PROCEDE_EDUC_PUBLICA + IN_SEXO_ALUNO + NU_IDADE_ALUNO, 
family = binomial, data = nor1)

Deviance Residuals: 
Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.3535  -0.7779  -0.6651  -0.4668   2.8123  

Coefficients:
                                 Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                    -0.3802707  0.0112696 -33.743  < 2e-16 ***
CO_CATEGORIA_ADMINISTRATIVA5   -0.5030216  0.0063270 -79.504  < 2e-16 ***
CO_COR_RACA_ALUNO1             -0.0452001  0.0081445  -5.550 2.86e-08 ***
CO_COR_RACA_ALUNO2              0.2784830  0.0144464  19.277  < 2e-16 ***
CO_COR_RACA_ALUNO3              0.1527192  0.0067474  22.634  < 2e-16 ***
CO_COR_RACA_ALUNO4              0.2388296  0.0210065  11.369  < 2e-16 ***
CO_COR_RACA_ALUNO5              0.0357580  0.0516736   0.692  0.48894    
IN_RESERVA_VAGAS                0.7116092  0.0474497  14.997  < 2e-16 ***
IN_RESERVA_ENSINO_PUBLICO      -3.1344320  0.1919678 -16.328  < 2e-16 ***
CO_TURNO_ALUNO                 -0.0157669  0.0055981  -2.816  0.00486 ** 
IN_RESERVA_RENDA_FAMILIAR      -9.8526964 14.0635939  -0.701  0.48356    
IN_FIN_NAOREEMB_PROUNI_PARCIAL -0.3676032  0.0206161 -17.831  < 2e-16 ***
TP_PROCEDE_EDUC_PUBLICA1        0.1709269  0.0054290  31.484  < 2e-16 ***
IN_SEXO_ALUNO                   0.1497493  0.0055368  27.046  < 2e-16 ***
NU_IDADE_ALUNO                 -0.0328465  0.0003694 -88.911  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

Null deviance: 876350  on 808601  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 857364  on 808587  degrees of freedom
AIC: 857394

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 9
```

**Preciso criar cenários tipo:**
CO_COR_RACA_ALUNO=1, TP_PROCEDE_EDUC_PUBLICA1=1, NU_IDADE_ALUNO<30

Os outros parâmetros podem ser pela média mesmo.

**Que me retornem a chance (ou probabilidade) de IN_FIN_REEMB_FIES=1 ou 0**

Já tentei pelo pacote mfx (que retorna os efeitos marginais) mas ele não aceita.
Alguém tem alguma sugestão?

Comment: Rafaela, você pode clarificar sua pergunta? 1. Você não forneceu os dados para reproduzir a análise. 2. Não está claro o problema de programação que você precisa resolver. 3. Não está claro o que você tentou no pacote mfx nem porque não deu certo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rafael, uma alternativa seria fazer o seguinte.

- calcular a probabilidade predita p/ cada um dos indivíduos da sua amostra usando o seu modelo e a função `predict`.
- filtrar na sua amostra apenas os casos do seu cenário de interesse
- calcular a média da probabilidade predita no banco de dados filtrado

Como você não disponibilizou um banco de dados, vou utilizar um que aparece neste [link](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/dae/logit.htm).

```
# ajuste do modelo
mydata <- read.csv("http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/data/binary.csv")
mydata$rank <- factor(mydata$rank)
mylogit <- glm(admit ~ gre + gpa + rank, data = mydata, family = "binomial")
```

Aqui são usados três indices para prever se um aluno será aceito numa graduação (variável admit):

- gre: Graduate Record Exam scores
- gpa: grade point average
- rank: 1 a 4, é o prestígio da instituição de onde provém o aluno

Agora se, por exemplo, você quiser saber a probabilidade de um aluno que vem de uma instituição com `rank = 1` e `gre > 500` não importando o `gpa`, pode fazer assim no R:

```
# prever a probabilidade de resposta
mydata$prediction <- predict(mylogit, type = "response")

# filtrar o banco de dados apenas com os casos do seu cenário
library(dplyr)
aux <- mydata %>% filter(rank == 1, gre > 500)
mean(aux$prediction)
[1] 0.577473
```

Se quisesse prever p/ quem tem `rank = 1` e `gre < 500`:

```
aux <- mydata %>% filter(rank == 1, gre < 500)
mean(aux$prediction)
[1] 0.3751226
```